# Checking the modification date does not work

Tags: c, linux, daemon

I have a problem with checking the modification date.
fprintf prints in the console for every file in the folder the same number equal zero.

```c
while (1) {
    source = opendir(argv[1]);
    while ((file = readdir(source)) != NULL) {
        if (file->d_type != DT_REG)
            continue; 
        stat(file->d_name, &file_details);
        fprintf(stderr, "Name: %s, Last modify: %ld  \n", file->d_name, file_details.st_mtime);
    }
    closedir(source);
    sleep(5);
}
```

Comment: Error checking! You don't have any. You need to add it. My guess is that `stat` returns `-1` with `errno == ENOENT`.

Comment: And a hint about what I think is the problem: `file->d_name` is just the file-name, not a full path.

Comment: How can i get a full path?

Comment: @kamilm758 You have to build it by concatenating the directory name and the file name, with `/` inbetween of course. Another way is to enter the directory being scanned, with `chdir()`.

Answer (score 0):

You must construct the path to the directory entry ans pass it to `stat`. You currently pass the entry name, which only works if you are enumerating from the current directory.

Furthermore, you should test the return value of `stat` to detect any problem. This would have shown that `stat` fails with the current code.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

...

char path[1024];
while (1) {
    source = opendir(argv[1]);
    if (source == NULL)
        break;
    while ((file = readdir(source)) != NULL) {
        if (file->d_type != DT_REG)
            continue; 
        snprintf(path, sizeof path, "%s/%s", path, file->d_name);
        if (!stat(path, &file_details))
            fprintf(stderr, "Name: %s, Last modify: %ld\n", path, file_details.st_mtime);
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot stat %s; %s\n", path, strerror(errno));
    }
    closedir(source);
    sleep(5);
}
```

Comment: Ad a check that `opendir` succeeded?

Comment: If date of modification is bigger then file was modified later?